# AttributeError: 'Widget17_Sorter' object has no attribute 'get_data_from_database'

Tags: python, import, module

Actually I don't see what I am doing wrong here but I guess it is a very simple and basic problem:

Module 1 called Widget17_Sorter.py:

```
class Widget17_Sorter(object):

    def get_data_from_database(self, database_name, user, password, host ):
        ...do stuff here...
```

Module 2 called Test_Widget17_Sorter.py (actually a unit test)

```
import Widget17_Sorter

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    ...do some other stuff here...

    def test_get_data_from_database(self):
        sorter = Widget17_Sorter.Widget17_Sorter()
        raw_data = sorter.get_data_from_database( self.database_name, 
                                    self.user, self.password, self.host )
```

When executing the test I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: test_get_data_from_database (__main__.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestWidget17_Sorter.py", line 50, in test_get_data_from_database
    raw_data = sorter.get_data_from_database( self.database_name,
AttributeError: 'Widget17_Sorter' object has no attribute 'get_data_from_database'
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try importing this way:

```
from Widget17_Sorter import Widget17_Sorter
...
my_widget = Widget17_Sorter(...)
my_widget.get_data_from_database(...)
```

...and put both scripts in the same folder...

Comment: Thanks but actually this had no effect. Instead I get an error that get_data_from_database cannot be imported. Which makes sense because it is a concrete method.

Comment: Can you type the message you are getting after importing this way?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestWidget17_Sorter.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Widget17_Sorter import get_data_from_database
ImportError: cannot import name get_data_from_database

Comment: Yeah I already tried that. It does not work either. The same error message

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer. Actually I made a very very stupid mistake. I have two project containing the same Modules and I did not notice that I was actually working in the wrong project. So it was impossible for python to find the method I was looking for.